# aggregating variables errors in r

Tags: r, aggregate, indicator

I am attempting to aggregate a dataframe by the columns of the indicators by a month variable and everytime I run the code I get a different error but mainly it says "Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default" and "Error in `[.data.frame`(twitdata, c("dei_div"), by = twitdata, c("month"),  : unused arguments (by = twitdata, FUN = true, na.rm = true)"

```
#1. clear environment of all variables----
rm(list=ls(all.names=TRUE))

#2. install necessary packages----
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(rebus)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(reshape2)
library(openxlsx)
library(ggplot2)
library(tables)
library(readr)
library(readtext)
library(stringi)
library(janitor)
library(data.table)
library(readxl)
library(plyr)
library(quanteda)
library(spacyr)
#3. set working directory----
setwd("C:/Users/sarah/Downloads")

#4. import data----
twitdata             <- read.csv("twitter_text_20200213_share.csv",stringsAsFactors = TRUE)


#5. clean data (remove spaces & symbols)----
twitdata$text    <-gsub('\\s+',"",twitdata$text)
twitdata$text    <-gsub('[[:punct:]]',"",twitdata$text)

#6. adding dei/sj indicators----
twitdata$dei_div   <- as.integer(grepl("divers",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))
twitdata$dei_eq          <- as.integer(grepl("equiti",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_in          <- as.integer(grepl("inclus",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_jc          <- as.integer(grepl("justic",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_ch          <- as.integer(grepl("chang",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_po          <- as.integer(grepl("polici",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_op          <- as.integer(grepl("oppress",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_pu          <- as.integer(grepl("perpetu",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_di          <- as.integer(grepl("discrimin",twitdata$text, 
                                                                   ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_dis         <- as.integer(grepl("disadvantag",twitdata$text, 
                                                                    ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_disp         <- as.integer(grepl("dispar",twitdata$text, 
                                                                     ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_und          <- as.integer(grepl("underserv",twitdata$text, 
                                                                    ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_race          <- as.integer(grepl("race|racial",twitdata$text, 
                                              ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_ra          <- as.integer(grepl("race|racial" != "grace","brace",twitdata$text, 
                                              ignore.case=TRUE))


twitdata$dei_disparit     <- as.integer(grepl("disparit",twitdata$text, 
                                                                    ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_alice            <- as.integer(grepl("ALICE|assetlimit|incomeconst",twitdata$text,
                                                                    ignore.case=TRUE))

twitdata$dei_blm         <- as.integer(grepl("blm|blacklivesmatter",twitdata$text, 
                                              ignore.case=TRUE))

#7. adding pandmeic indicator----
twitdata$pandemic         <- as.integer(grepl("pandemic|covid|corona|virus",twitdata$text,
                                                                    ignore.case=TRUE))
#8. adding month variable----
twitdata$month            <- as.character(substr(twitdata$created_at, 6, 7))

#subset sj/dei in a datdrame
sjedeiwords <-c("dei_div","dei_eq","dei_rc","dei_in","dei_jc",
                "dei_ch","dei_po","dei_op","dei_pu","dei_di",
                "dei_dis","dei_disp","dei_und","dei_rac","dei_disparit")

#count total
library(sjmisc)
row_count(twitdata, count = 1, append = FALSE)

#aggregate by each word per month
dei_monthly <------- aggregate.data.frame(twitdata[c("dei_div")], by=twitdata [c(twitdata$month)]
                                          , fun = "sum", na.rm = true)
agg = aggregate(twitdata,
                by = list(twitdata$dei_div),
                FUN = sum)

#problem is when fun = sum, it works when fun= mean, that is not applicable however

#9. aggregate by the occurrence of the DEI/SJ words by month----
#(wip)

deisjmonthly                               <-aggregate(twitdata[c("dei_div","dei_eq","dei_in","dei_jc",
                                                                  "dei_ch","dei_po","dei_op","dei_pu","dei_di",
                                                                  "dei_dis","dei_disp","dei_und","dei_race","dei_ra","dei_disparit",
                                                                  "alice")],
                                                       by=twitdata[c("month")],
                                                       FUN=sum,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: I can't answer your question but this is weird: "dei_monthly <------- aggregate ...." You are assigning to an object and then reversing the sign of the 6 times before the assignment. Try this:  "foo <- 1" then ask for 'foo' and you'll get '1'. If you add further minus signs the object will change: "foo <-- 1" then ask for foo and you'll get '-1'. So when you have an odd number of minus signs after the assignment operator (<-) you change the sign of your object. In your case you were lucky it was even.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).